# How to hide a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with id="menu" in my index.html file and I want to hide it using jQuery. In my script.js I wrote:

```
window.onload = function() {
  prepareEventHandlers();
}

function prepareEventHandlers() {
  var hideDiv = $("#menu");
  var crtButton = $("#hide");
  crtButton.onclick = function() {
    hideDiv.hide();
  };
 }
```

But when I press the button on the webpage the div is still there, the only way that works is if in the index.html I write:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="$('#menu').hide()" id="hide">HideDiv</button>
```

but I don't want to use it since it is bad style, so how can I make this work using my script.js code?

Comment: Like Lucas mentioned, `crtButton` is a jQuery object. You can either use his code or in your code use `crtButton[0].onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with Lucas' answer or modify your own code

`crtButton` is a jquery object so it doesn't have `onclick` property. Edit onclick property of the DOM element instead (which is `crtButton[0]`)

Or just skip jQuery and use `getElementById`

```
    window.onload = function() {
      prepareEventHandlers();
    }

    function prepareEventHandlers() {
      var hideDiv = document.getElementById("menu");
      var crtButton = document.getElementById("hide");
      crtButton.onclick = function() {
        hideDiv.style.display = 'none'
      };
     }
```

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested, but I get a type error saying that hideDiv is not a function, it is thrown on line hideDiv.hide(); any idea why?

Comment: but wouldn't display 'none' yank it out of the DOM tree completely?  I'm trying to avoid that since I might to bring it back if requested by the user.

Comment: it just hides it. you can do `hideDiv.style.display = ''` to show it back

Comment: You probably should stick to jQuery IMO, and learn it's API. It will save you a lot of time and effort on the long run.

Answer (score 1):

`crtButton.onclick` won't work because `crtButton` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element.

Do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide").on("click", function() {
        $("#menu").hide();
    });
}
```

This is the *jQuery way*. Note that I replaced `window.onload` with a [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback, which will be called as soon as the DOM is ready (sooner than `onload`). I also used the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind to the event.

Comment: or you can do `$(crtButton).click(...`

Comment: crtButton is already a jQuery object. You don't have to re-query it

`crtButton.click(function(){})` will work. That being said, `.on('click', function(){})` is the newer and preferred method

Comment: Unless that button is dynamic theres no need to use .on, .click will do the same thing

Comment: I didn't say it won't work. Its just better as it works with dynamic elements and can be easily unbound

Comment: @tymeJV what do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @tymeJV I think you're confusing `.on(event, function)` with `.on(event, selector, function)`. The former is what superseded `.bind`. The latter is what superseded `.live`.